# Laravel configuration error: The cipher and / or key length are invalid

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, error-handling

I am using laravel 5 i have tried possible solution on similar question on stack but that didn't helped me . Below are my updated files that i edited

My .env file is updated with appkey see here

generated appkey with php artisan command key generate and put that in . env

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=[9vkErFVjzUX3ozuOcD7T7KTHNKP2FBNB]

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=blogdb
DB_USERNAME=rootDB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Also Updated app.php file cipher and appkey manually

```
  'key' => env('APP_KEY', '[9vkErFVjzUX3ozuOcD7T7KTHNKP2FBNB]'),

  'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

Don't know why it is generating 34 bit app key using php artisan command

Comment: remove the brackets

Comment: ok going to do it

Comment: make sure you do this both in .env file and in app.php

Comment: done its working now

Comment: I think that was a basic mistake i should delete this question

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob thanks for a quick review

Comment: not a bad question...don't delete it

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob ok sure

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob Since you want to keep the question, maybe make an answer out of your comment. Personally, I think the question is too local (in its current form at least).

Answer (score 2):

please use

```
php artisan key:generate
```

or use

```
php artisan list
```

to view all artisans.
then .env file simillar:

```
APP_KEY=base64:s1TFa5c254BawHqjiRznrmFatra08lRuIwNLDm2inr4=
```

and app.php simillar:

```
    'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

Answer (score 0):

All Data in my question was correct but as i was using it laravel first time so when api key generated it came with '['  ']' brackets but it was not supposed to be used with that so correct api key and files code is below -

In env File ( APP_KEY without brackets )

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=9vkErFVjzUX3ozuOcD7T7KTHNKP2FBNB

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=blogdb
DB_USERNAME=rootDB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Also Updated app.php file cipher and appkey manually  ( APP_KEY without brackets )

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY', '[9vkErFVjzUX3ozuOcD7T7KTHNKP2FBNB]'),

'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

Comment: this was answer that @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob reviewed quickly and it get solved